# Repetitive values when INSERTing a lot of rows in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I want to `INSERT` 4200 rows into MySQL with PHP (laravel 4), but after row 127, the rest of the rows will remain as the same as the row 127!

[image: Example]

The query:

```
DB::insert("INSERT INTO unit_word (unit_id, word_id)
          VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2),..., (1, 127), (1, 128), ..., (1, 4200)");
```

and in MySQL:

```
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 32M
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like the column type is `TINYINT`, as it can only hold integer values between -128 and 127.

Comment: change the word_id data type to bigint

Comment: I looked everywhere and played with many things... and I didn't check that!!! Thank you both

Comment: Someone write an answer for @javidhb to accept. We don't do that by writing "SOLVED" in titles on SO.

Comment: Remember to post your schema in questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `word_id` column type set as `TINYINT`, which can only hold integer values between -128 and 127. Set the column type to `BIGINT` to use it as a primary key